# Reload data on a UITableView with animation (the table hasn't got sections)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

I have a `NSArray` with 20 elements. I want to show these 20 elements dynamically on a `UITableView`. I have disabled scroll on the tableview, and I want to remove the first NSArray element every 1 minute, and then reload `UITableView` to don't show the element that I have removed and show the remanning ones. And I want to do it with animation.

Searching over internet I have found some examples about how to do it using sections, but I have only one section on the `UITableView`.

In a nutshel,

1. Load 20 elements into a NSArray.
2. Show these 20 elements on an `UITableView` with scroll disabled.
3. For loop to remove first NSArray element every minute.
4. After remove, do `UITableView` reload with animation.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to reload the entire table. Just remove the object from your array (once a minute or whatever). The object that you remove will be at index XXX in your array. And then call :

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:XXX inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this :

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:intvalue(your indexPath) inSection:0];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];

[yourtableview  deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```